# showing progress bar or loading icon untill page fully loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm populating large JSON data to Jtable. It takes approx 1 min to load. What I want is show progress bar untill the page fully loaded.I've gone through some Stackoverflow solution but doesn't work for my problem.

```
 records = eval(objLangugaeTranslatorExt.listRecords(self._lastPostData));
                data['Records'] = records;
                data['TotalRecordCount'] = Object.keys(records).length;
                self._removeAllRows('reloading');
                self._addRecordsToTable(records);//Here I add the records to table taking too much time.
```

Please help me with this,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use `eval()`!** It is dangerous for using it on user-data.

You can do one thing, in your `_addRecordsToTable()` function, show the loading DOM element:

```
$(".loading").show();
```

And after the loading code, you can put:

```
$(".loading").hide();
```

And for the HTML:

```
<div class="loading"></div>
```

Just after the `<body>` tag. And in the CSS:

```
.loading {position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: url("loading.gif") center center no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.The problem is its very large application I didn't write that function _addRecordsToTable(). How can I put this $(".loading").show();

Comment: @ArunFebi either you need to show us the full cod somewhere or you need to write that function...

Comment: this is the function:  _addRecordsToTable: function (records) {
            alert(records);
            var self = this;
            $.each(records, function (index, record) {
                self._addRowToTable(self._createRowFromRecord(record));
            });
            self._refreshRowStyles();
        }